# Adding title below photo

Tags: html, css

I'm displaying some photos on website. **I want to add a photo title below each photo**. I tried many ways but it still doesn't work.
This is html and css:

```
<div id="albumListContent">
<img id="a42" class="albumImg" width="150px" alt="not found" src="photo_with_any_size.jpg">
<img id="a56" class="albumImg" width="150px" alt="not found" src="photo_with_any_size.jpg">
<img id="a59" class="albumImg" width="150px" alt="not found" src="photo_with_any_size.jpg">
<img id="a62" class="albumImg" width="150px" alt="not found" src="photo_with_any_size.jpg">
<img id="a63" class="albumImg" width="150px" alt="not found" src="photo_with_any_size.jpg">
<img id="a64" class="albumImg" width="150px" alt="not found" src="photo_with_any_size.png">
</div>


.albumImg, {

    /* center photos */
    vertical-align: middle;

    /* add some margin for elegance */
    margin: 1em;

    /* Photo hover effects */
    opacity: 0.8;   

    /* Border style and border color */
    padding:8px;
    border:solid;
    border-color: #dddddd #aaaaaa #aaaaaa #dddddd;
    border-width: 1px 2px 2px 1px;
    background-color:white;
}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
This is my Jquery which generates the above html:

```
                var albumListHTML = '';
                albumListHTML += '<div id="albumListContent">';
                if(num > 0) {               
                    for(var i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
                        albumListHTML += '<img id="a' + data[i].album_id + 
                                         '" class="albumImg" width="150px" src="' + 
                                         data[i].album_cover + '" alt="not found" title="' + 
                                         data[i].album_name + '"/>';                            
                    }                       
                } else {
                    albumListHTML += 'No album found.';
                }
                albumListHTML += '</div>';
                $('#albumListContentWrapper').append(albumListHTML);
```

I tried adding < span > which wraps < img > and set "float: left" to force the text to be below the < img >, then center text with text-align. The problem is the < img > is "float:none" so the text is floating away.

```
                    for(var i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
                        albumListHTML += '<span style="">';
                        albumListHTML += '<img id="a' + data[i].album_id + 
                                         '" class="albumImg" width="150px" src="' + 
                                         data[i].album_cover + '" alt="not found" title="' + 
                                         data[i].album_name + '"/>';

                        albumListHTML += '<span style="float: left; text-align: center">' + data[i].album_name + '</span>';
                        albumListHTML += '</span>';
                    }
```

Comment: what you have tried till now.

Comment: The question is not much clear. Can you please tell what you have done and what you actually want to do in detail. So that we can help you.

Comment: Not clear, from where you are getting title of the images. If they are static you could create one more div below each picture and apply some CSS class to that. your complete code may help to assist otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look at the sample code here: http://jsfiddle.net/D29ny/

I am not sure how you are going to show the title. If you are setting manually, the sample code will rectify your problem.

I hope this helps!

Comment: hi, but how to vertical align the image_wrapper(s) if the images are different heigh. It should be like the photos in my first post.

Comment: @Emerald214 To vertical align, remove the property "float: left" from the CSS under ".image_wrapper"

Comment: not work, when I remove it, the photos are in vertical order, not on the same line. It must be like the image in my first post.

Comment: OK. So you need to show 3 images in a row with different heights

Comment: You can split into rows. the images shown in a row will place under a <div> and each row will have a common style.

Comment: I don't know how to do. What must I show?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057620/vertical-align-photos-on-the-same-row

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/bcNqY/

Adjust numeric values as necessary.