# Vertical align photos on the same row

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to vertical align the photos in this case with CSS?
I tried add vertical-align, but it doesn't work with div.

[image]

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
.imageWrapper {
    margin: 1em;
    float: left;
/* vertical-align: middle; */   
}

.imageTitle {
    text-align: center;
}

.row {
    float: left;
}

#albumList {
    width: 600px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="albumList">

    <div class="row">
        <div id="w1" class="imageWrapper">
            <img src="1.jpg" width="150px"/>
            <div class="imageTitle">Title1</div>
        </div>

        <div id="w2" class="imageWrapper">
            <img src="2.jpg" width="150px"//>
            <div class="imageTitle">Title1</div>
        </div>

        <div id="w3" class="imageWrapper">
            <img src="3.jpg" width="150px"//>
            <div class="imageTitle">Title3</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div id="w4" class="imageWrapper">
            <img src="4.jpg" width="150px"/>
            <div class="imageTitle">Title1</div>
        </div>

        <div id="w5" class="imageWrapper">
            <img src="5.jpg" width="150px"//>
            <div class="imageTitle">Title1</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[THIS IS WHAT I TRIED]
I can do it with JQuery but some photos added on the fly and some added on error handler (image_not_available.jpg), so this approach too hard to apply.

```
var maxHeight = 0;
var maxID = 'nothing';
$('.imageWrapper').each(function(i){
    var height = $(this).height();
    if(height > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = height
        maxID = $(this).attr('id');
    }
});

$('.imageWrapper').each(function(i){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if(id != maxID) {
        var minus = maxHeight - $(this).height();
        $(this).css('margin-top', minus / 2);
    }
});
```

Comment: Look on the right > there are a million examples on how to vertical align in CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#albumList {
  display: table;
}

.imageWrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 350px; /* for example, guess you have to specify it */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

could you just set the line-height the same as height of div.row

```
.row {
height: 200px;
line-height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To use vertical align in a div you need to use the display property `table-cell`.

Heres an example:
HTML -

```
<ul>
<li class="item">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/150" alt="Little kitten">
</li>
<li class="item">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/60" alt="Little kitten">
</li>
<li class="item">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/160" alt="Little kitten">
</li>
```

CSS -

```
.item{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Hopefully that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`vertical-align` only applies to inline elements (or elements inside a table cell), so use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left` to position the images side by side and then vertical align will work:

```
.imageWrapper {
    margin: 1em;
    display: inline-block
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I've found was

```
#footer-widgets .widget {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Source](https://siteorigin.com/thread/vertically-align-all-images-in-row/)